# Firebase Auth - authStateChanges() called multiple times in simple Flutter Web app

Tags: flutter, web, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I am developing a simple app that makes the user sign in anonymously using Firebase Auth. But when I refresh the browser (Chrome), I can see that the Home screen is rendering twice in a few milliseconds.

I have seen other questions for older Firebase versions, but I did not find the solution.

```
class AppRoot extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppRoot({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Error!');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print("HOME"); // calling twice -> calling HomeScreen initState twice -> fetching resources twice...
              return const HomeScreen();
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Main:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Auth Test',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: const AppRoot(),
    );
  }
}
```

Why is authStateChanges rendering HomeScreen twice? It should only once after the user logs in anonymously.

Comment: If you `listen` to `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` and `print` the values you get (with a timestamp next to them), what does it show?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It is printing once. I can see the problem now. I was using `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` as stream directly in the `StreamBuilder` instead of keeping it in a variable in a `StatefulWidget`, and that was causing the rebuild.

Comment: Good to hear that you figured out out @Gero 